# Autocomplete Jquery UI not working on JSON

Tags: json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

## I'm having trouble with my jqueryUI autocomplete function.

Here's the code for my script.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function (){
  $("#names").autocomplete({
    source: "tags.php"
  });
});
</script>
```

Here is the code for my tags.php

```
<?php
  include_once("connect.php");
  $sql = "SELECT full_name FROM tbl_names";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $data = array();
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row['full_name'];
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Here is the code for my connect.php:

```
<?php
  $server = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $database = "yrock_attendance";
  $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);
  if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed!");
  }
?>
```

And here is a part of an output of my tags.php

```
["ABANEZ, JAMICHA","ABANI, MART JOSEPH","ABINION, KARL AXEL ","ABLAO, YZEL RONNELAINE","ACIDELLA, MARY GRACE","ACUNA, NATH MIGUEL"]
```

Every time I type on my input box, it shows all my data and it doesn't filter anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. At this time, I see you have 2 versions of jQuery loaded. This can produce unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

If you review:

> **String**: When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one (must support CORS). The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results. For example, if the source option is set to `"http://example.com"` and the user types `foo`, a GET request would be made to `http://example.com?term=foo`. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.

So you need to do the filtering yourself in SQL or in JavaScript with the resulting data. Here is a SQL example:

```
<?php
  include_once("connect.php");
  $term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['term']);
  $sql = "SELECT full_name FROM tbl_names WHERE full_name LIKE '$term%';";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $data = array();
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row['full_name'];
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

For this basic example, I used `mysqli_real_escape_string()` yet it would be best to use a Prepared Statement. See More: https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Thank you very much. I did what you told me and modified the script a little bit. Instead of "tags.php", i changed it to "tags.php?="